# How do I make a search statement in java with a while loop and stop and return the object when it's found

Tags: java

I've been stuck with this java search statement.
I'm trying to search in an Array of Products called stock which is initialized in the class Stockmanager, which contains an `id` field a name and a stock level.
these product objects are made in a separate class called Product.

constructor Stockmanager:

```
// A list of the products.
private ArrayList<Product> stock;

/**

 * Initialise the stock manager.

 */
public StockManager()
{
    stock = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Product constructor:

```
// An identifying number for this product.
private int id;
// The name of this product.
private String name;
// The quantity of this product in stock.
private int quantity;

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Product.
 * The initial stock quantity is zero.
 * @param id The product's identifying number.
 * @param name The product's name.
 */
public Product(int id, String name)
{
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    quantity = 0;
}
```

There is an accessor method in Product to retrieve a product object id:

```
/**
 * @return The product's id.
 */
public int getID()
{
    return id;
}
```

Now in Stockmanager, I have my search method, but it seems this method will complain about incompatible datatypes if I don't use my for-each loop or will complain about not having a return statement if I do use a for-each loop.

the method:

```
/**

 * Try to find a product in the stock with the given id.

 * @return The identified product, or null if there is none

 * with a matching ID.

 */
public Product findProduct(int id)
{
    int index = 0;
    boolean searching = true;

    for (Product item : stock)
    {  
       while(searching && index < stock.size())
       {
            if (item.getID() == id)
            {
                searching = false;
                return item;
            } else {
                index++;
            } 
            if(searching)
            {
                return null;
            } else {
                return item;
            }
        }
    }        
}
```

It's got to be possible to have a `while` loop in this return statement because I don't need the method to look further in the array if it's found a hit.
Please, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: what exactly do you think this does: if(searching)
            {
                return null;
            } else {
                return item;
            } ?

Comment: What *specifically* is the error?  "It complains about..." isn't a specific error.  Consider the logic of needing return statements... What would this method return if any one of your loops is never entered?  The method *must* return *something*.  Why do you have a `while` loop at all when you always return on the first iteration of that loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reason to have two nested loops, and you don't need the `index` and `searching` variables.

You just need a single `for` loop. If you find a matching `Product`, you return it. If not, you return `null` when the loop ends.

```
public Product findProduct(int id)
{    
    for (Product item : stock) {  
        if (item.getID() == id) {
            return item;
        }
    }
    return null;    
}
```

Comment: You are absolutely right, I just wasn't sure if the method kept searching the array if it found a hit, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8 you could use the Stream API

```
public Optional<Product> findProduct(int id)
{
    return stock.stream().filter(item -> item.getID() == id).findAny();
}
```

Before Java 8 simply implement it using a for loop.

```
public Product findProduct(int id)
{
    for (Product item : stock)
    {  
       if (item.getID() == id) 
       {
                return item;
       }
    }   
    return null;     
}
```

Comment: your "Before Java 8" version won't compile

Comment: `getID` return an `int`, not an `Integer`, use `==` instead of `equals`.

Answer (score 0):

Just Remove `if(searching)` condition,

```
/**

     * Try to find a product in the stock with the given id.

     * @return The identified product, or null if there is none

     * with a matching ID.

     */
    public Product findProduct(int id){
        for (Product item : stock){  
           if (item.getID() == id){
                return item;
            }
        } 
      return null;
    }
```

Why do you need while loop? There is no need of while loop.

Comment: congratulations by proposing to solve the issue by providing code that won't compile. Not sure the OP will understand how to fix this so it will work